# Rails packing CSS yslow import directive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, yslow, assets

I have an RoR application with multiple CSS files.

YSlow complains about to many http request for the css files.

Now I have installed Jammit, to compress my css files into one file.

That works, but when some CSS file has an "import" directive, i get still an http request instead of simply get an single css file with all the included files.

How is the best method to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some other packaging options available as well like asset_packager etc . You could try one of them .

Comment: I have installed the asset_packager, still having import directives in my generated css file